# Twilio environment variable error

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, pycharm, twilio

[Twilio-Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) works fine if I place my account_sid and auth_token directly into the code but will not work when I set them to environment variables. I'm using PyCharm and set them by going to edit configurations > Environment variables, just as I have done with other variables in the past with no problems. I reference them in my code with:

```
account_sid = os.environ["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
auth_token = os.environ["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
```

Which throws the following error:
`twilio.rest.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 404 error: The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/'<my account_sid>'/Messages.json was not found`

I tried exporting the variable on the CLI and running the code there but got the following error:
`KeyError: 'twilio_account_sid'`

I have no idea what I am overlooking. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For OS X El Capitan, add environment variables:

- open terminal, then

  `cd ~/`

  `vi .bash_profile`

once in vi editor editing the file, get into insert mode (press i) then add these two lines:

```
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID="AC0123456789abcdefabcdefabcdefabcd"
export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN="0123456789abcdefabcdefabcdefabcd"
```

get into vi command mode (press escape) save and quit

```
:wq
```

- reboot your computer

To check environment variables after reboot, open terminal, type `printenv`, you should see them on the list.

In your script, to use the environment variables, try this

```
import os

account_sid = os.environ.get('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')
auth_token  = os.environ.get('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN')
```

For configuring Windows environment variables take a look at my answer

[Twilio Auth windows enviro variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750822/twilio-auth-windows-enviro-variables/37755577#37755577)

Comment: I have the same error using ```get```. I'm on OSX if that makes a difference. It's weird, I've set environment variables this same way in the past with no problem.

Comment: What version of OS X are you on?

Comment: El Capitan version 10.11.3

Comment: Updated my answer for El Capitan.

Comment: Thank you for that. Is there a way to specify the virtual environment I am using for the project?

Comment: You're welcome. The os.environ.get() scope has to do with your OS X user environment while the PyCharm environments have to do with Python, different things.